# express req.pipe() does not work

Tags: node.js, express

1. I want to listen to incoming POST request in express.
2. I want to pipe this request to another server
3. I want to receive response inside express handler (I dont want to pipe response to express res stream)

For now I have following code:

```
app.post('server1',function(req,res,next){
    var request = require('request');
    req.pipe(request.post('server2')).pipe(res);

}
```

So this does not work - request is not even piped to server2 - I checked it and there is no incoming request.

---

I solved points 1 & 2 like this:

```
var bodyParser = express.bodyParser();

app.use(function(req,res,next){

    if(req.path == '/server1' && req.method == 'POST') {
        return next();
    }
    else {
        bodyParser(req,res,next);
    }
});
```

Not very nice but it works - it just disables bodyparser for a single route (POST /server1).

But I still don't know how to obtain json response body from piped request - I have following code:

```
app.post('/server1',function(req,res,next){

    var request = require('request');
    var pipe = req.pipe(request.post('/server2'));

    pipe.on('end',function(){

        var res2 = pipe.response;
        console.log(res2);

    });
});
```

`res2` object has correct statusCode and headers and so on but it does not contain body - how I can get this from the `res2` object? `/server2` returns some data in json but I dont know how to read it from response...

Comment: It probably means that `req` has already been read to completion -- to its [`'end'`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) -- possibly by `bodyParser()`. A stream won't *restart* for a new `.pipe()` after that.

Comment: Well so how I can make it not been read to completion? Or how I can make a stream from already read request? I have to pipe request because there is file upload there...

Comment: I edites my question - your comment on `bodyParser` helped me a lot - I just need to solve last point (3).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski All my post requests stopped piping after making a few changes including configuring a body parser for all endpoints.. don't know how long I'd have been banging my head against the desk if it weren't for your comment - Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 18):

It doesn't work because bodyParser intercepts all the bodies with parsers

Answer (score 8):

I think you're almost there. You should listen on `data` events on the pipe to collect the response:

```
app.post('/server1',function(req,res,next) {
  var request   = require('request');
  var pipe      = req.pipe(request.post('/server2'));
  var response  = [];

  pipe.on('data',function(chunk) { 
    response.push(chunk);
  });

  pipe.on('end',function() { 
    var res2 = Buffer.concat(response);
    console.log(res2);
    // don't forget to end the 'res' response after this!
    ...
  });
});
```

However, since you solved the "bodyParser() getting in the way" problem, you can also use your initial pipe setup if you just want to return the response generated by server2 (also, be sure to use proper URL's when using `request`).