# Unobtrusive middle-ware for Expres.js to inspect request body

Tags: express, body-parser

Does there exist a thirdparty middleware or a way to create such middleware for Express.js that allows for intercepting all requests and inspecting the request's body content without affecting subsequent middleware such as [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) or route endpoints which may rely on the raw body such as [express-http-proxy](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy)?

From what I can tell bodyParser itself seems to work in a somewhat obtrusive way that does not allow a route to override the default parsing behavior. The express documentation describes how [request.body](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body) is filled in by middleware such as bodyParser. This behavior of bodyParser makes sense from simplicity and performance perspective but doesn't make it a great candidate for creating middleware which needs to inspect the contents of a request and let the remaining portion of the app working without modification. This is especially true seeing that depending on the parsing middleware the results may be in entirely different formats. After some digging I'm left wondering if it's generally possible to pull this off with express or perhaps once you read the request body you eliminate the ability to make use of further middleware such as bodyParser or express-http-proxy which expect to access the body directly.

Possibly related:

- [express req.pipe() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728039/express-req-pipe-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the [raw-body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-body) package with express middleware like so:

```
var getRawBody = require('raw-body');
var typer = require('media-typer');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  getRawBody(req, {
    length: req.headers['content-length'],
    limit: '1mb',
    encoding: typer.parse(req.headers['content-type']).parameters.charset
  }, function (err, string) {
    if (err) return next(err)
    req.text = string
    next()
  })
})
```

If your only concern is performance, I wouldn't worry too much about body-parser as it's unlikely to have a massive performance impact. If you can, I'd suggest you just use body-parser with a typical express middleware `app.use(..)` to inspect the request body.

Comment: The main issue with body-parser is that subsequent explicit middleware declarations such as `app.use('api/*', bodyParser.json(), function (req, res, next) { ... })` will break since req.body won't be json at that point if prior bodyParser middleware had already _parsed_ the body in a different format (ex. text, raw, urlencode,...).

Comment: I tried the raw-body module as posted but unfortunately it appears to break express-http-proxy. Not sure if there is anything I can do about that.

Comment: Your suggestion to sue raw-body has led me to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy/issues/32) which describes my exact problem. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy/pull/36) as well that changes express-http-proxy to accommodate obtrusive middleware.

Comment: It's good you know where the incompatibility lies, you could always copy the suggested pull request if you need it asap.

Comment: Yes, and as a slightly little off topic thought, tools like bodyParser could have modified the request to add properties such as bodyJson, bodyText, ... instead of just body and leaving other middleware to make guesses as to what that object is. Additionally, if not already possible, the node request stream could have been exposed in a way that it could be "replaced" with another stream by middleware to achieve less obtrusive effects on subsequent middleware. I'm still digesting the source to see if that is even possible as it is.